# Non-Injective differentiable map between manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ and $N$ be two smooth manifolds with dimensions m and n, respectively, with $m>n$. Let $f:M\to N$ a smooth map ($C^\infty$). Show that this map can't be injective.

My try: I was wondering how could I reduce this problem to the tangent space, using the differentiability condition, to work with vector spaces, where I know how to proof this result. But I was unable to do it, so any help will be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Among all points of $M$, choose a point $x$ where the rank of the differential $d_x f$ is biggest. It then follows that in some small open neighborhood of $x$, the function $f$ has constant rank. Then by the constant rank theorem it'll be obvious that $f$ cannot be injective there.

Comment: +1 as it is much easier than my approach! I will emphasize on the importance to take a point $x$ where $\textrm{rank}(\mathrm{d}_xf)$ is maximal to conclude that $f$ has constant rank near $x$. This follows from the fact that locally the rank can only grow as minors of a matrix are continuous.

Comment: Can you explain why the constant rank theorem gives the desired result?

Comment: @Rhcpy99 Let $r$ be the rank of $\mathrm{d}_xf$, one has $r\leqslant\dim(N)<\dim(M)$ and according to the constant rank theorem there exists diffeomorphisms $\varphi,\psi$ such that:
$$(\varphi\circ f\circ\psi)(x_1,\ldots,x_m)=(x_1,\ldots,x_r,0,\ldots,0)$$
in a neighborhood of $x$. Therefore, $\varphi\circ f\circ\psi$ is not injective and so is $f$.

Comment: We actually have $m > n$, so that the function is more like $(x_1, \ldots, x_m) \to (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$. It's not injective because it forgets some coordinates.

Comment: @Pedro This will happen if and only if $f$ has full rank, but perhaps there is no $x$ such that $\textrm{rank}(\mathrm{d}_xf)=n$. Anyway, $(x_1,\ldots,x_m)\mapsto (x_1,\ldots,x_r,0,\ldots,0)$ also forgets some coordinates as $r\leqslant n<m$.